# Move DOM element to top of the parent and after selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li>
         <span>category name</span>
         <ul class="level2"></ul>
         <ul class="level2"></ul>
         <ul class="level2"></ul>
         <ul class="level2"></ul>
         <ul class="level2"></ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

I want selected ul that is with level2 class to move to top of the 
ul.level1 li but it should be after ul.level1 li span.

Actually this is regarding move elements in bootstrap tree
http://jsfiddle.net/umutc1/eyf9q87c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this JSFiddle, think it's what you're after:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/traceline/grdmv8Lu/)

Essentially, you hook onto the event that triggers the move, find the thing you want to move, find where you want to move it to and use the .after() jq function to do the move.

HTH

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.level2").click(function(e){
        var clickedUL = $(e.target).closest("UL");
        $("ul > li > span").after(clickedUL);
    });
});
```